# Allow user to select which open window the macro should refrence

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Can I have a running macro prompt the user to select one of the open excel documents?

I have a macro that is pretty straight forward and just opens several docs and pastes values from some spots to other spots and saves some, closes others without saving, etc.

One of the documents that the macro needs to pull numbers from, however, gets emailed to me.  I can count on the format of the file to be the same, the name is different every time.

I would like to be able to simply open the emailed excel spreadsheet along with my macro program, and then when it comes time for the macro to grab information out of the emailed excel document, to just ask me which of the open excel documents is the right one to use.

I found `Application.GetOpenFilename` which is similar to what I want, but lets you select a saved location.  Normally my file isn't saved anywhere (at least nowhere in particular, I'm sure it is somewhere in temp space) and it'd be easier to just open the file directly from the email and have the macro ask which open file is the right one to use.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a UserForm with a ComboBox populated with the open workbooks and WorkSheets. Display the choices and select one.

```
Sub ViewListOfOpenWorkBooksAndWorkSheets()
Dim book As Workbook, sheet As Worksheet
 For Each book In Workbooks
  For Each sheet In book.Worksheets
   UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem book.Name + "!" + sheet.Name
  Next sheet
 Next book
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```